# react-native : update object with setState

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to update `object` using `setState`?

```
updateState = () => {
    let updateThis = '2019-06-30

   //I want to update pressedDate's updateThis with '2019-06-30'

   this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
    pressedDate: {
       ...pressedDate,
       updateThis : {dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true}
     }
    }))
  }
```

**This is what I want to do**: I want to update pressedDate's `updateThis` with `'2019-06-30'`

I think this code is right but when I console.log(this.state.pressedDate) after I run this code, my `object` `updateThis` isn't replaced to '2019-06-30'

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i get you completely, but you should set the `updateThis` key to the the date

```
    updateState = () => {
    let updateThis = '2019-06-30

   //I want to update pressedDate's updateThis with '2019-06-30'

   this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
    pressedDate: {
       ...pressedDate,
       updateThis : updateThis
     }
    }))
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your code will give me what I want but what about other values like this `{dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true}` I want to update these values at the same time.

Comment: please can you update the question , stating the desired shape of the 'state'. from your question i assumed you wanted to replace the 'updateThis' key and replace the object to a string containing the date.

Comment: thanks but isn't this updating object using setState? I am not quite sure how you want me to edit my question.