# react-native : updating object's value using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update `object's value` using `setState`

In my code I am trying to update `Date` to `2019-06-22` and also update other values such as `{dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true}`.

**My Code:**

```
this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
  pressedDate: {
     ...pressedDate,
      Date:'2019-06-22', :
      {
        dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true
      }
   },
  }))
```

This will give me an error. I think my code is okay but don't know what is wrong.

Any advise or comments would be really appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

**Thanks @bkm412 I have the solution:**

```
const newDate = '2019-06-22'
   this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
     pressedDate: {
     ...pressedDate,
      [newDate] :
      {
        dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true
      }
   },
  }))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-native : update object with setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535209/react-native-update-object-with-setstate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
  pressedDate: {
     ...pressedDate,
      ['2019-06-22'] :
      {
        dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true
      }
   },
  }))
```

If you want to use variable

```
const newDate = 'any date';
this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
  pressedDate: {
     ...pressedDate,
      [newDate] :
      {
        dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true
      }
   },
  }))
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But could you please check if the second code? it gives me an error saying that unexpected keyword 'const'

Comment: Oh.. sorry. I changed variable name

Comment: I think the code `const newDate = '2019-06-22'` has to be out side of `setState`. I moved it and it works great thanks. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want update `Date` to `2019-06-22` is okay, But
I don't know what you to update into `{dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true}`, He has no key.

You can try below code:

```
this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
  pressedDate: {
     ...pressedDate,
     Date:'2019-06-22',
     dots: [vacation, massage, workout],
     selected: true,
  },
}));
```